# Quark flow diagram for $\rho^0 \rightarrow \pi^0+\gamma$

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

So $\pi^0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u\bar{u}-d\bar{d})$ and $\rho^0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u\bar{u}-d\bar{d})$ except with a higher angular momentum, this angular momentum is taken by the photon.

How do I draw the quark flow diagram when the particles are in a superposition (do I just pick one way)?

Comment: Can you specify what you are going to do with this Harari-Rosner diagram? How do your write the $ρ^0$? There is a sum of two alternatives, one in which the photon couples to the *u*s,  plus one in which it couples to the *d*s.

Comment: the question just says draw it